# Some reference for Stokes flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am an undergraduate and I am doing my final project about Stokes equations, which can be written in 3-D as:

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\mu \left({\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}}+{\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}}}+{\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial z^{2}}}\right)-{\frac {\partial p}{\partial x}}+f_{x}&=0\\\mu \left({\frac {\partial ^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}}+{\frac {\partial ^{2}v}{\partial y^{2}}}+{\frac {\partial ^{2}v}{\partial z^{2}}}\right)-{\frac {\partial p}{\partial y}}+f_{y}&=0\\\mu \left({\frac {\partial ^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}}+{\frac {\partial ^{2}w}{\partial y^{2}}}+{\frac {\partial ^{2}w}{\partial z^{2}}}\right)-{\frac {\partial p}{\partial z}}+f_{z}&=0\\{\partial u \over \partial x}+{\partial v \over \partial y}+{\partial w \over \partial z}&=0\end{aligned}}}$$

I am able to find the fundamental solution. Now, I am trying to find a reference about 3 of the following:

1. For a rigid body moving on a fluid, how do you find the velocity field of the fluid based on the boundary integral.
2. Find out about the reciprocity relation.

I have found a book by C. POZRIKIDIS regarding these problems, but I cannot really understand the materials. I am writing this post to ask about other references (if any). Please let me know if you guys have any material about these topics. Thank you so much.